# Do I need to call Marshal.DestroyStructure after copying a struct to a byte[]?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

Actually I have many questions, so I try to describe them in detail, thanks for your patience.

I want to write a some generic methods for wrapping native APIs, just like ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory.

Take WriteProcessMemory for example, I found some ways to do them:

**1.GCHandle**

```
// Write memory: Non-Array
var lengthInBytes = (IntPtr)Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
var tHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    // Call native api;
}
finally
{
    tHandle.Free();
}

// Write memory: Array
var lengthInBytes = (IntPtr)(data.Length * Marshal.SizeOf<T>());
var tHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
     // Call native api;
}
finally
{
    tHandle.Free();
}
```

This way is very simple, but the only problem is the object that to be pinned must be a built-in value type ( except fixed array, but the type of the element in array is subject to the same requirements ), . So I found another way: Marshal.AllocHGlobal method.

**2. The members in Marshal class**

```
//Write memory: Non-Array
var lengthInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
var memPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lengthInBytes);
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(data, memPtr, false);
    // Call native API
}
finally
{
    Marshal.DestroyStructure<T>(memPtr);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memPtr);
}

// Write memory: Array
var perSize = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
var arrayLength = data.Length;
var lengthInBytes = arrayLength * perSize;
var memPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lengthInBytes);
var baseAdr = memPtr;
try
{
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(item, baseAdr, false);
        baseAdr += perSize;
    }
    // call native API.
}
finally
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++, baseAdr -= perSize)
    {
        Marshal.DestroyStructure<T>(baseAdr);
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memPtr);
}
```

This way will alloc some memory, copy data, and even traverse array twice, But it supports the reference types, and I was satisfied with it, But then I got a idea: how about using Byte[] instead of IntPtr?

Specifically,The extern method is:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern Boolean WriteProcessMemory([In] HandleRef hProcess, [In]IntPtr lpBaseAddress, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Byte[] lpBuffer, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]IntPtr nSize, [Out, Optional, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
```

And the code in method is:

```
var perSize = Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
var buffer = new Byte[perSize];
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var pBuffer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr<T>(data, pBuffer, false);

    //Call native API.

}
finally
{
   // Question!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    Marshal.DestroyStructure<T>(pBuffer);
    handle.Free();
}
```

**So there is a question: do I need to call Marshal.DestroyStructure method?**

MSDN says

> StructureToPtr(T, IntPtr, Boolean) copies the contents of structure
>   to the pre-allocated block of memory that the ptr parameter points to.
>   If structure contains reference types that marshal to COM interface
>   pointers (interfaces, classes without layout, and System.Object), the
>   managed objects are kept alive with reference counts. All other
>   reference types (for example, strings and arrays) are marshaled to
>   copies. To release these managed or unmanaged objects, you must call
>   the DestroyStructure(IntPtr) method before you free the memory
>   block.

And this method is "Marshals data from a managed object of a specified type to an ***unmanaged block of memory***."

But variable buffer is a Byte[](In managed memory), so if I wont call DestroyStructure, can GC release the reference types in T? ( By the way, in my test, this way is much faster than second way, even though Marshal.DestroyStructure method has also been called too... )

And more questions is, will there be more ways to get the pointer of generic T?  And if there are any mistake in the solution above?

Comment: Since you made it generic, you can never be 100% sure whether DestroyStructure is required.  But *if* it would be needed then you already have a very big problem, the underlying native pointer will cause a hard crash.  You'll either crash your app with ReadProcessMemory() or crash the victim process with WPM().  Pointers are only valid in the process who created them.  So no, not needed.  Notable perhaps that this is not the kind of code you want to make generic, too easy to put you to sleep without worry.  You can overload the DllImport declarations for different struct types.

Comment: @HansPassant  Thank you for your post, yes, I have overloaded them: One for built-in value type (unsafe code, lpBuffer is void*  ), and one for Byte array or String ( lpBuffer is Byte[] ), and one for generic type( lpBuffer is IntPtr ), but it seems that the third one is useless. StructureToPtr only requires that the data must be formatted, In my understanding, this method dont check if the T is marshalable, so  DestroyStructure is required. But in my case, the data has be checked by Marshal.SizeOf……But I am not sure if I my understanding is right.